# How to bind to a method on ViewModel with data from View

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I currently have one view with 3 fairly simplistic view models.  For the sake of this discussion, we will focus on 2 of the three view models.

The View is a User Management user control.  It contains a DataGrid that has its ItemsSource binding set to a UserListViewModel.  This view model simply displays user information in the data grid.

The User Management View also contains some other controls, such as buttons for adding new users and removing users.  Those buttons are currently bound to a second view model called UserManagementViewModel.  For example, the Remove button will successfully call the RemoveUser method on the UserManagementViewModel.

My question is, via XAML (as I hate code-behind), how can I pass the SelectedItem property of the DataGrid (bound to UserListViewModel) into the RemoveUser method call on the UserManagementViewModel?  I realize that, in the MVVM design pattern, my view model can't look into the view to retrieve the information necessary, so there must be a way via binding to pass that information into the method.

XAML code examples (or links that show how) to perform similar functionality would be appreciated.  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use a commandparameter

```
 <Button Command="{Binding RemoveCommand} CommandParameter="{Binding Elementname=gridUser, Path=SelectedItem}" />
```

or your UserManagementViewModel have access to the UserListViewModel then you need a command without commandparameter and simply use the SelectedUser property of your UserListViewModel instance

```
 public void ExecuteRemove()
 {
    var userToRemove = this._myUserListViewModelinstance.SelectedUser;
    ...
 }
```

Comment: Having the two view models 'know' about each other breaks the MVVM, pattern, though.  I think using a command parameter is exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @Jason Two view models knowing about each other does *not* break the MVVM per se. The idea of MVVM is that view models don't know *how* they will be presented. But they still get to know *what* will be.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you seek is commanding with a command target bound to the datagrid's selecteditem where one can route such information from the datagrid; say when a button is pressed.

See [Commanding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx) on MSDN